# mongoose : how to validate field depend on other field value

Tags: mongodb, express, validation, mongoose

I want to require field depend on other field value; I have field paypaleEmail , I want it to be required when field role is "particular" otherwise not required.

```
 paypalEmail: {
        type: String,
        required: function () { return this.role == 'particular', 'Paypal Email is required' },
        trim: true,
        validate: {
            validator(email) {
                return validator.isEmail(email)
            },
            message: '{VALUE} is not a valid email!',
        },
        lowercase: true,
    },
```

when try to send request I got paypalEmail is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "required" function should return a boolean.

Your

```
function () { return this.role == 'particular', 'Paypal Email is required' }
```

Unconditionally returns string 'Paypal Email is required' which evaluates to `true` when casted to bool.

```
function () { return this.role == 'particular' }
```

Should do what you expect.